# JRuby - Monkeypatching as poor man's security manager?

Tags: java, security, jruby, sandbox, monkeypatching

Is there any thing wrong with *selectively* monkey-patching all Ruby core classes (File, Kernel, IO etc) to create a sort of access control?

My JVM will be running untrusted user code, and for some reasons I ***don't want*** to use Java's security manager. So, I turned to Ruby open classes for implementing my own sandbox. I had monkey-patched almost all the core classes, but for some reason I feel this is not secure enough. Am I being paranoid, or is this really a bad solution?

In a related question, Is there a way to selectively exclude Java from my Ruby runtime. My libraries need Java, but I don't want the user's to be able to access it. I've included Java in my libraries which in turn have been "required" into the user scripts.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: You should post 2 questions.   Also its not clear what you need form an access controller  or whats wrong with the JVM's secuirty manager.

Comment: For access controller, I just need to block certain operations like file access, thread manipulation etc. Regarding security manager, I don't want to use it since it causes performance problems. :)

Comment: What performance problems did you run into using a Java SM ? 
If none, I recommend go for it since I doubt you'll get better performance by monkey-patching core classes for access checks ...